# Have Python print lines at different times

Tags: python, time

I'm making a simple game for homework. I would like to print lines, but have them print 1 second apart from each other. How would I go about doing that?

Something that would delay the prints I guess. So like

```
"Hello"
"My name is blahblah"
"This is blah blah"
"blah blah"
"What's your name?"
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time.sleep(seconds)` pauses for a second, in your case:

```
import time
strings = ["Hello","My name is blahblah","This is blah blah","blah blah","What's your name?"]

for txt in strings:
    print txt
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.sleep(1)` to give a 1 second delay

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

while(1):
    print("-")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# coding:utf-8 -*-

import  time

def print_line(lines):
    """
        print every line in lines per 1s 
    """
    assert type(lines) in (list, tuple, str)
    if type(lines) == str:
        lines = (str,)

    for line in lines:
        print line
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """test print line with a simple tuple"""

    test_data = "Hello", "My name is blahblah", "This is blah blah","blah blah","What's your name?"
    print "print one sentence per second, begin ..."
    print_line(test_data)
    print "finished!"
```